# Optimize download speed using Java

Tags: java, performance, download, fileinputstream

I have a method in java which will download files from web, but the download through java code is slower than if i download it using any browser.

My code is as follows,

```
 public void downloadFile(String downloadURL) {


            System.out.println("Starting file download .....");


            BufferedInputStream in = null;
            FileOutputStream fout = null;
            try {
                URL u = new URL(downloadURL);
                HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                String fileName = uc.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
                fileName = YouTubeDownloader.parseResponse(fileName, "filename=\"", "\"");
                System.out.println(fileName);

                if (uc.getHeaderField("Content-Length") == null) {
                    System.out.println("File Length zero!!!!");

                }




                float fileSize = Float.parseFloat(uc.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));

                in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());

                System.out.println("File size : " + fileSize);


                fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Dinesh\\" + fileName);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                int count = 0;
                int downloaded = 0;
                while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {

                    downloaded += count;
                    int downloadPercentage = (int) ((downloaded / fileSize) * 100);
                    System.out.println(downloadPercentage);
                    fout.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                System.out.println("File download completed.....");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    }
```

Is the download speed too slow because of the lower buffer size ?

Can I increase the buffer size or how to optimize the same for slower download speed ?

What things do I have to modify ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you are writing to a slow device, the performance should be limited by the network speed/server transfer rate. Buffering the outputstream might help, and so may increasing the read size to 8192 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to monitor the progress, try this:

```
Path saveFile = Paths.get("C:\\Dinesh", fileName);
Files.copy(uc.getInputStream(), saveFile);
```